# Sum and Product game

Tags: puzzle, modal-logic

Two perfect logicians Steve and Pete, who have never met, before are imprisoned by an eccentric villain. "I have two positive integer numbers x and y" he says to them. "I will tell Steve the sum x+y, and Pete the product xy. If at any point either of you know the two numbers x and y, you may shout them out, and I will release you both. You may take turns saying statements giving the other information, but you may only communicate about your state of knowledge. If any part of your statement contains any information about the numbers themselves, you'll both be shot. If any of you tries to communicate any other information not directly implied by the statements, you'll both be shot."

Can the logicians always figure out the numbers?

As an example, if the two numbers are 1 and 6, a potential conversation could go:

P: I don't know the numbers

S: I don't know the numbers

P: I don't know the numbers

S: I don't know the numbers

P: I know the numbers! They are 1 and 6! (S would have known if the numbers were 2 and 3)

Or another example, if the numbers are 2 and 4:

P: I don't know the numbers

S: I didn't know whether you knew until you said that (could have been 1 and 5, and P would obviously have known, as 5 can only be factorized as 1x5)

P: I know the numbers! They are 2 and 4! (S couldn't have said that if the numbers were 1 and 8)

Is there always some strategy like this? (Note that the logicians are not able to communicate beforehand, and each logician must attempt to give useful information based on what they know)

Edit: The question has been raised whether just saying "I don't know" until someone figures it out would work for all possible answers. It doesn't. In order to show this, all one needs to do is construct a "cycle" of possibilities, with each consecutive pair alternatively having the same sum or the same product. Those pairs would be indistinguishable for S and P for all time unless more information is given than "I don't know the numbers"

A simple cycle is given by (2,5)->(3,4)->(1,12)->(3,10)->(5,6)->(1,10)->(2,5).

One could argue that simply eliminating the possibility of having 1 as one of the numbers would solve this problem. But by merely doubling the cycle, this is shown to be false: (4,10)->(6,8)->(2,24)->(6,20)->(10,12)->(2,20)->(4,10). Thus, removing 1 only delays the problem.

Edit 2: As the condition about only talking about states of knowledge is ambiguous, I have decided that a new version is: The logicians can only say either they know/don't know the numbers, or that they knew/didn't know what the previous person just said (from which the other logician can infer that they don't know the numbers, because otherwise they would have said that)

For example, if the numbers are 3 and 4, a conversation could go:

P: I don't know the numbers (could be 1 and 12 or 2 and 6)

S: I knew you didn't (even if the numbers were 2 and 5 or 3 and 4, P wouldn't have known)

P: I didn't know that (S couldn't have said that if the numbers were 2 and 6. However, this doesn't yet eliminate 1 and 12)

S: I know the numbers! They are 3 and 4! (the previous statement eliminated the other options)

Edit 3: 02/05/2020: It's starting to seem like it still might take the logicians quite a long time to figure out the numbers, and the logic gets increasingly difficult to follow. I wouldn't be surprised if for some pairs of numbers they might not be able to figure it out. Here's a particularly interesting (solvable!) case (shortened to aid readability). The numbers are 1 and 10:

P: I know you know that I don't know the numbers

S: I know you know that I didn't know that

P: I know the numbers now! They are 1 and 10!

Comment: Presumably, the positive numbers are positive integers?

Comment: See discussion at https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c146h150971

Comment: Much discussion at https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~sillke/PUZZLES/sp.txt

Comment: @LSpice, yes, positive integers

Comment: Those seem to be about very specific cases, where there are restrictions on the sum, and the reader has to figure out the numbers. I'm asking if, given any two numbers, the logicians can figure it out.

Comment: So at the beginning the logicians only know that $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$? The solution to this puzzle depends strongly on the given domain of $x,y$. But here you're asking a different question, namely about the strategy of the logicians. However, how do you define "state of knowledge"? What is the difference with "information about the numbers themselves"?

Comment: Let's restrict things a bit: Suppose they only keep saying "I don't know" until one of them finds out the numbers. Is there a number which we can construct where they'll never figure it out? My guess is that for any starting pair of positive integers, eventually they'll get it; this is based on the fact that products of two distinct primes have a pretty high density.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault, with regards to state of knowledge. Let's say that the two logicians can only say things like "I know/don't know the numbers", and "I knew/didn't know what you just said before you said it".

Comment: @JoshuaZ I think that is too strong of a limitation on the conversation. I'll edit my question to show what I mean, in particular, to show that even (3,4) is impossible to figure out using that method.

Comment: Are the logicians allowed to agree on a strategy before the conversation?

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault No, they have never met before.

Comment: Then I don't understand precisely your question "Is there always some strategy like this?". Do you mean to ask whether the logician S (or P) has a winning strategy regardless of what the other logician will say? That's different from finding a common strategy.

Comment: Okay, what I'm asking is this: Given the constraints of the problem, can the logicians figure out the numbers? No strategies, no coded information, only logic.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't get it. Do you mean to ask whether there exists at least one sequence of declarations which enables the logicians to find the numbers?

Comment: Yeah that is a good description of it